# Geometric progression formula. how to get to n = something?

Tags: calculus

I know that the formula for Geometric progression is
$$ a_n = a_1\cdot q^{n-1} $$

I want to get an expression like that: " $n =$ something ". I have no idea how to do it, because the n is in the exponentiation.

Comment: Are there any limitations on the variables? For example, do you know that they are all positive real numbers?

Comment: there are no  limitations

Comment: Then there will be no simple "expression" for $n$ that always works. For example, there are infinitely many solutions for $n$ in the equation $$0=0\cdot 1^{n-1}$$ and in some other equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\log |a_n|=\log |a_1| +(n-1)\log |q|.
$$

Comment: You probably know this, but it should be stated that this works only if $a_1,a_n$ and $q$ are all positive real numbers.

Comment: @RoryDaulton You are right. I've edited my answer, but of course for $|q|=1$ an expression for $n$ cannot be found.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you found a restriction that I missed. +1 for that.